# Cloud Foundry Bind services/cups datasource number of connections

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-connectors

I am using hikari with spring boot, local testing I can see 50 active connections. After I deployed to cloud foundry , I am only able to see 10 active connections.

spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=50

Seems like cloud foundry bind service is trying to overwrite my application's configuration. How can configure this number in cloud foundry?

maybe someone get help from this link, it says if you are running serious application in production , you need to configure DataSourceConfiguration

http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-connectors/spring-cloud-spring-service-connector.html#_relational_database_db2_mysql_oracle_postgresql_sql_server

https://spring.io/blog/2015/04/27/binding-to-data-services-with-spring-boot-in-cloud-foundry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are including `spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors` in your project, then the Spring Boot database properties aren't used. Spring Cloud Connectors will create and configure the `Datasource` bean automatically, unless you write the Java code to manually configure it.

As you found in the [Connectors docs](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-connectors/spring-cloud-spring-service-connector.html#_relational_database_db2_mysql_oracle_postgresql_sql_server), you can write code like this to configure the connection properties, including pool size.

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    PoolConfig poolConfig = new PoolConfig(5, 30, 3000);
    DataSourceConfig dbConfig = new DataSourceConfig(poolConfig, null);
    return connectionFactory().dataSource("database-service-name", dbConfig);
}
```

If you want to use Boot properties instead of writing code like this, you can remove `spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors` from your project and configure the Boot properties using the [`vcap` properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/cloud/CloudFoundryVcapEnvironmentPostProcessor.html) provided by Boot when apps are run on CF. Your `maximum-pool-size` property should be honored if you configure the connection in this way.

Answer (score 0):

I had to look up Hikari. According to [this article](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) it is a jdbc connection pool.

I am assuming then, you deployed Hikari as an app within Cloud Foundry and created a CUPS service from it. Is that correct?

You *cannot* modify the service thru the CUPS definition. It is only creating you an instance of that service.

Try setting the pool size either in the `bootstrap.yml` or by setting environment variables on the Hikari app to pass the default values. You may need to tweak the app to accept those variables at runtime.

If that doesn't work, you may have to create your own service broker, or generate a tile. That would give you options to manipulate the service.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I did try to set up in bootstrap.yml and setting environment variables.  And I did try to use dhcp and c3p0 as well, seems all these database connection pool settings are overwritten by cloud foundry service/cups binding.

Comment: If you look at the `cf cups --help`, you will notice there is not an option to manipulate the actual service details anywhere in that. 
The service itself has to be configured to set defaults. 
You may have to write a service broker for it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the cloud foundry connector would override your properties and to configure it you'd have to declare a bean as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42285115/5105263). Note that the configuration for this was limited and therefore cloud foundry introduced [java-cfenv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42285115/5105263). You can add this library in your build.gradle as follows:

```
implementation 'io.pivotal.cfenv:java-cfenv-boot:2.1.2.RELEASE'
```

Then you can remove the `spring-cloud-spring-service-connector` and `spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector` libraries. Any configurations that you declared under the overriden beans can now be configured under `application.properties` as you would do in a normal spring boot project. Also make sure to add the following properties in your manifest:

```
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: cloud
JBP_CONFIG_SPRING_AUTO_RECONFIGURATION: '{enabled: false}'
```

Refer this [repository](https://github.com/pivotal-cf/redis-reference-architecture) that provides a sample of how you can use this with redis.