# Springboot 1.5.7 - Hikari CP 2.7.8 configuration is ignored

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp

### Issue

1. While running unit test, all working well. following is hikari related configuration in `application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:...........
spring.datasource.username=...
spring.datasource.password=...
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=3
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifeTime=2000000
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

2. However, after deploy to PCF clould platform, **the maximumpoolsize is set to 4**, a number comes from nowhere. the `application-prod.properties` of deployment is almost same as above except the url/username/password.

### Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Don't you have a `application-prod.properties` file overriding that when Spring profile is set?

Comment: Where are you deploying the app? Perhaps the datasource is bound by your cloud infrastructure?

Comment: @Matt, yes, we do have a application-prod.properties with different url/username/password, everything else is identical

Comment: @StephaneNicoll, the app is deployed to PCF could platform. The datasource is a ORACLE service provided by PCF. But it should not take over connection pool configuration?

Comment: Found an answer for this, will verify - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081731/cloud-foundry-bind-services-cups-datasource-number-of-connections